# html form size of a particular input

Tags: html

I have a form with input like:

```
id="mytext" size="35"
```

This gives me a Box with 35 characters.

I want to have that with a Box of size 35 characters, but with 2 lines. how can I set that in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just confused, you want `size` or you want to `limit` your characters?

Use `maxlength` attribute if you want to `limit` the characters to 35

```
<input type="text" maxlength="35" />
```

Or you can use textarea if you want 2 lines

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" maxlength="35"></textarea>
```

Note: `size` is not a valid attribute for `<textarea>`, if you want to increase the width, use `cols`

```
<textarea row="2" cols="35"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thankq ..is this syntax correct: <input type="text" name="Details" id="mytext" <textarea rows="2" size="35"></textarea> />

Comment: using <textarea rows="2" cols="20" maxlength="35"></textarea>. how can I tell the id, type and all

Comment: @TheLearner you welcome, and btw just confirmed, `size` is not a valid attribute for `<textarea>` so if you want to increase the size of textarea horizontally use `cols` like this -> <textarea rows="2" cols="35"></textarea>` and if you want to limit characters than use `maxlength` attribute

Comment: note that the `maxlength` attribute for the `textarea` tag is `html5` and not working in IE and Opera http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<textarea id="mytext" rows="2" size="35"></textarea>​
```

Comment: That sets number of rows to 2, defaulting number of columns. The `size` attribute is invalid here, and ignored.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Actually `size` is not a valid attribute for `textarea`, I made a fiddle, noticed that it isn't changing, so went to w3cvalidator and confirmed and yup, it was invalid

Answer (score 1):

For two lines you could use two input fields

```
<input type="text" name="line[]" maxlength="35" />
<input type="text" name="line[]" maxlength="35" />
```

The [] chars will group it up into an array-like on the server side.

PHP for example would let you access the two rows this way

```
$line1 = $_POST['line'][1];
$line2 = $_POST['line'][2];
```

You could also use the textarea tag for several lines but this natively can't be limited to two lines as far as I know

EDIT:

the textarea attributes cols and rows just define the display size. Input length isn't limited.

http://www.htmlref.com/reference/appa/tag_textarea.htm